# What is it.each follow by a template string?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I saw the following code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657098/jests-it-each-description-to-render-arrow-function-source-code-when-referre):

```js
....(more code above)

describe(findPairwise.name, () => {
  it.each`
    array        | predicate                                | expected
    ${[1, 2, 3]} | ${(l: number, r: number) => l === 1}     | ${[1, 2]}
    ${[1, 2, 3]} | ${(l: number, r: number) => r === 2}     | ${[1, 2]}
    ${[1, 2, 3]} | ${(l: number, r: number) => r === 3}     | ${[2, 3]}
    ${[1, 2, 3]} | ${(l: number, r: number) => l + r === 5} | ${[2, 3]}
    ${[1, 2, 3]} | ${(l: number, r: number) => l === r }    | ${[undefined, undefined]}
  `
  ('should return $expected for $array and $predicate', ({ array, predicate, expected }) => {

....(more code below)
```

I do not understand why he can do `it.each` follow by a template string, may I know what language feature is this?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout)? As they say it's a _tagged template_ literal, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hi, yes, it says `it.each`table`(name, fn)` is an alias, but I do not understand why it can be written this way

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah right, now I understand it, thanks!

Comment: (And frankly I wouldn't bother using it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72117404/3001761.)

Comment: I see, make sense, thanks for the informative link!